# Using Ubuntu Monospace with terminator on WSL

Tags: fonts, windows-subsystem-for-linux, terminator

I am attempting to configure `terminator` to use [Ubuntu Monospace](https://design.ubuntu.com/font/) under WSL.

What's the proper `font =` setting the `.config/terminator/config` to accomplish this?

I am running `Xming` as my X Server. Does the font need to reside on the X server side?